# How do I send output to a printer using TKinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have the following code in a TKinter (8.6) program. When I invoke the Run_Report function the data is written as expected to the Editor. I would however also like it to print it to my printer. I have put in code which I think should do the job but it returns an error:

```
lpr.stdin.write("Population Data"+"n".encode())
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

The code for the functions is as follows:

```
def Run_Report():

    import subprocess
    lpr = subprocess.Popen("/usr/bin/lpr", stdin=subprocess.PIPE)

    sPrinciple=e_SelectInv.get()

    Sql=("SELECT Principle as Investment, RptDate as Report_Date, printf('%,.2f',RptVal) as Report_Value, printf('%.2f',ExchRate) as Exchange_Rate, printf('%,d',RptVal*ExchRate) as Total_Value FROM MyInv WHERE Principle = ?" +
             "order by Id Asc")

    conn = sqlite3.connect(r'/home/bushbug/Databases/TrackMyInv')
    curs = conn.cursor()
    curs.execute(Sql,(sPrinciple,)) 
    col_names = [cn[0] for cn in curs.description]
    rows = curs.fetchall()
     
    x = PrettyTable(col_names)
    x.align[col_names[0]] = "l"
    x.align[col_names[1]] = "r"
    x.align[col_names[2]] = "r"
    x.align[col_names[3]] = "r"
    x.align[col_names[4]] = "r"
    x.padding_width = 1
    
    for row in rows:
        x.add_row(row)
    
    print (x)
    tabstring = x.get_string()
    output=open("export.txt","w")
    output.write("Population Data"+"n")
    output.write(tabstring)
    lpr.stdin.write("Population Data"+"n".encode())
    output.close()
     
    conn.close()
```

Can someone please help me correct whatever is wrong in the above?

Thank you in anticipation.

Comment: Change `lpr.stdin.write("Population Data"+"n".encode())` to `lpr.stdin.write(("Population Data"+"n").encode())`.  Actually should `"n"` be `"\n"` instead.

Comment: acw1668. Thank you. I tried that but it still gives the same error message. Any other thoughts?